# Differring behaviour of Date.parse?

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
alert(Date.parse('Mar 1 1990'));
```

in jsFiddle, this returns a datetime integer, as expected. On my machine, it returns... a timestamp string?

`Thu Mar 01 1990 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)` vs `636267600000`

Comment: You are simply noting different behaviors here, not actually asking a question.

Comment: While I'm at it, Date.UTC would work, except when I try to verify the result in PHP via `date(y-m-d, $var);`, the datetime is always a month off...

Comment: My question is... why is there a different behaviour, besides the obvious fact that they are different environments? It's a little worrying to think that somewhere out there, clients are getting returned completely different results than intended...

Comment: No repro. I get a number on jsFiddle with Firefox.

Comment: @Julian H. Lam - Please _edit_ your question and add any relevant information directly to it, instead of in comments.

Comment: Hint #1: JavaScript months count from 0.

Comment: Kenny - yeah, that's what I get too. My own machine, on the other hand, seems to not return what I want... Tomalak - perfect, thanks.

Comment: I get the integer timestamp in every environment I've tested (as per the spec). What browser/version(s) are you getting the string?!

Comment: BTW, the JavaScript that runs 'through jsFiddle' must also run on your machine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMAScript Language Specification

> **15.9.4.2   Date.parse (string)**
>
> The parse function applies the
>   ToString operator to its argument and
>   interprets the resulting String as a
>   date and time; **it returns a Number**,
>   the UTC time value corresponding to
>   the date and time. The String may be
>   interpreted as a local time, a UTC
>   time, or a time in some other time
>   zone, depending on the contents of the
>   String. The function first attempts to
>   parse the format of the String
>   according to the rules called out in
>   Date Time String Format (15.9.1.15).
>   If the String does not conform to that
>   format the function may fall back to
>   any implementation-specific heuristics
>   or implementation-specific date
>   formats. Unrecognizable Strings or
>   dates containing **illegal element
>   values** in the format String shall
>   cause Date.parse to **return NaN**.

What you probably did wrong was that the two tests were not the same:

`alert(Date.parse('Mar 1 1990'));` returns a number (always)

`alert(new Date('Mar 1 1990'));` returns the string you mentioned

(because toString method is called on the date object)

Comment: +1 I would tend to agree in that the two tests must differ in some way! However `alert(Date('Mar 1 1990'));` will actually output the _current date_, not the string mentioned. When `Date()` is called as a function then any arguments are ignored and a string representation of the current date/time is returned. However, `alert(new Date('Mar 1 1990'));` _will_ return the string mentioned (depending on your locality).

Comment: @w3d yep, this is what i wanted to write. It's a bit late here. Thanks for pointing out.